# How can I install Windows 10 from USB (via Media Creation Tool) to a blank new SSD? (Updated)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I've given up on cloning my old HDD, and thinking of exchanging the defective ssd I recently bought, and buying a new SSD alongside a CD copy of Windows 10. As for my old files, ill just back them up to something and swap them over when the new drive is running.

What equipment will I need? What are the steps to do this and do it right? This laptop was bought in 2013 with Windows 8 preloaded. What kind of problems might I run into?

Also, if I can't get a CD, how should I go about this? Should I buy a blank cd, and burn the ISO to the CD? Buy a flash drive with it on? Download the ISO to the SSD by downloading the ISO from the web with the SSD connected to the computer via USB?

UPDATE: I finally found my product key for Windows via freeware out there, OemKey, and I don't have to pay for Windows again. That being said, what is the step-by-step to use this bootable media, that I'll make via the creation toolkit from MSFT, to get a working and fully functioning SSD going into my laptop? Previously, a shop had used an unlicensed Windows 10, but the SSD they put in took forever to reboot (4 mins) and I returned the SSD. I want to do this right finally.

Comment: Just install your SSD and then boot from Windows 10? You're not doing an upgrade right, its just straight install of fresh windows 10?

Comment: Yes, from a CD or keycode (my computer has an optical drive

Comment: The only possible problem you may have is if your laptop does not have driver for Windows 10. Beyond that, since its a fresh install - it will most likely have no issue. Just install Windows 10 - update your computer driver - copy your data back and it is good to go. PS: Most laptop will work with Windows 10.

Comment: Well my computer had Windows 10 with the HDD... does that mean I'm good to go?

Comment: If you still have a working computer - just download the driver for your laptop in advance. Just in case after installing Windows 10 - you don't have internet and can't download the driver afterwards .

Comment: Driver for windows 10? Should I then assume my old HDD has it because that's what it last ran when I had it in there?

Comment: No. It is best to get the driver from the laptop manufacturer website. It might work using the old HDD, but I don't know where it is being stored. So your best bet is to download from the manufacturer website.

Comment: How can I verify my laptop has a Windows 10 driver?

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson - Go the OEM website, look up your laptop model, download any drivers for your laptop.

Comment: All the drivers were downloaded when my laptop had the HDD inside. I also checked Samsungs OEM download page; no Windows 10 driver. The computer, with the HDD, was last on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a CD drive for your computer, you should be able to just load the CD into the drive, boot from the disk through BIOS, and it should prompt you to install Windows onto the new SSD if its connected.

Comment: What will I need to do afterwards to get the computer running like before?

Comment: Once you install Windows onto the SSD, it should prompt you to restart the computer, and it should be good to go.

Comment: Also, what if I can't find a CD? What if all I can get is a product code? Can I connect the SSD to the computer, download the ISO, and put it on the SSD?

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson - Nothing.  Windows will automatically activate itself.

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson That should work